# Play-Slick Instruction on How to Perform Custom Sorting using Case-When

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

Our project requries a custom sorting. And upon diving into the net I come up with the following SQL statements.

```
SELECT CountryName 
FROM   dbo.Country 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN CountryName = 'INDIA' THEN '1'
              WHEN CountryName = 'CHINA' THEN '2'
              ELSE CountryName END ASC
```

Can someone help me have this in Slick?

I already have this kind of query

```
contriesQuery.map(_.CountryName)
.sortBy(c => {
    val srt = {
       Case If(x.CountryName = "India") Then 1 
       Case If(x.CountryName = "China") Then 2
       Case Else CountryName  
    }
    srt.asc
})
.result
```

But it always showing me an error 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: for SELECT ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a query based on your approach and it is working as expected. I'm using slick 3 with PostgreSQL.

I believe that the correct syntax is

`Case If(...) Then ... If(...) Then ... If(...) Then ... Else ...`

for a better read you can write it as so:

`Case
    .If(...).Then(...)
    .If(...).Then(...)
    .If(...).Then(...)
    .Else(...)
    .asc`

Regards!